# Caractere Inválido em HTTP Request C#

Tags: c#, .net, http, request

Estou precisando desenvolver uma WebAPI que você passe uma Query e ele retorne a busca do google com titulo e url. Estou utilizando C# e .NET, quando faço a requisição HTTP pra receber os dados da página, ele está retornando os caracteres especiais como um "?", alguem tem ideia de como resolver isso?

Uma outra duvida, é do por que quando faço um request (get) pelo postman, ele retorna MUITOS dados, e com o C# (WebRequest) bem menos?[image: String retornada pelo WebRequest C#]

Segue o codigo:

```
            string sURL = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+this.Query+"&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL);

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        string myResponse = "";
        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            myResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return myResponse;
```

Fiz alguns testes com outros websites, e eles retornam perfeitamentamente os caracteres, aparentemente o problema é com o Google (Porém pelo Postman retorna perfeitamente)

Comment: Onde está o seu código?

Comment: Acabei de editar a pergunta

Comment: Tenta passar o encoding UTF-8 como segundo parâmetro do StreamReader, acho que isso resolve o problema dos caracteres.

Comment: @Francisco infelizmente não resolveu.

Comment: Esse código que você passou funciona bem, meus parabéns. Porém ainda falta ainda o código que manda o resultado que você encontrou para a página pois é ai que está o problema a maneira como está sendo passada o HTML, pela imagem está sendo passado com um texto .

Comment: @AugustoVasques isso, eu estou passando como texto, depois filtro esse texto para pegar apenas os títulos e urls (a parte que me interessa). Porém, o que está acontecendo, são esses caracteres inválidos que aparentemente vem direto da requisição, pois se faço requisições para sites como globo.com e uol.com.br, os caracteres chegam perfeitos.

Comment: Uf8 e HtmlEncode / HtmlDecode

Comment: Infelizmente também não funcionou.

Comment: Não é o caso de fazer então um `String.Replace(char, char)`? `return myResponse = myResponse.Replace('\ufffd',' ')`

Comment: O problema é que todos os caracteres em \ufffd são caracteres com algum tipo de acento, seja ele qual for ~ ´ ` ^

Comment: @FelipeChiarotti, view a minha resposta?

Answer (score 0):

A acentuação você resolve com a `CultureInfo` no seu `StreamReader`

```
string Query = "teste";

string sURL = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + Query + "&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sURL);

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
string myResponse = "";

var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"); 
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(),
        Encoding.GetEncoding(culture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage),false))
{

    myResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();

}
```

Agora os demais caracteres como por exemplo `\u003E` que representa o `>` estão no formato UNICODE porque são apresentados dentro de strings, são declarados dessa forma para evitar quebras em caracteres especiais e devem ser tratados em sua leitura desses conteúdos em especial.

Comment: Bom dia Leandro, desta maneira estou obtendo o seguinte erro (exception): System.NotSupportedException: 'No data is available for encoding 1252. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method.'

Comment: a solução é .net core?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta utilizar o encoding `ISO-8859-1`, fiz um test com código apresentado como teste e retornou os caracteres especiais.

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))
```

A imagem demonstra a resposta da request e seus caracteres especiais
[image: print com resposta em arquivo de request]